# Foreach array loop for JSON

Tags: php, json

Here is my PHP/JSON code:

```
$json_url = "http://dailydota2.com/match-api";
$json = file_get_contents($json_url);
$json=str_replace('},
]',"}
]",$json);
$decoded= json_decode($json);
$data=$decoded->matches[0];
foreach ($data as $value) {
print_r($value->team1->logo_url);
}
```

Now I have the following problem

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object

and

> Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$team1

I just want use `foreach loop` and then show my results in HTML.

Why I am getting the 2 mentioned problems and how can I show the correct results?

Comment: Why are you doing `str_replace` on the result?

Comment: Have you tried `var_dump($decoded)` ?

Comment: actually json works fine just foreach dont work i think i made mistake in foreach loop `matches[0]`gone be 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8

Comment: If you have narrowed down the problem to a certain part of your code, please edit the question to make clear what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

I have checked your code and have some notes and hopefully a solution:

1- You are trying to get non existing key from JSON data, that is the message telling you.

2- I am still not sure what do you get from the JSON API. But regarding to  [dailydota2 documentation](http://dailydota2.com/match-api-doc.txt) there is nothing called image_url under team1. I guess you are looking for logo_url or something like that.

3- Do not change the format of JSON as you do in your code, therefore delete following line:

```
$json=str_replace('}, ]',"} ]",$json);
```

Just leave the main JSON output from API as default.

4- When you try to get specific key from the decoded JSON/Array just use following way:

```
$data = $decoded->{'matches'};
```

in stead of

```
$data=$decoded->matches[0];
```

Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

5- And finally your `foreach loop` is working but needs the correct key:

```
foreach ($data as $value) {
    print_r($value->team1->logo_url);
}
```

When all these step is done, it should works.

Here is your final corrected code:

```
$json_url = "http://dailydota2.com/match-api";
$json = file_get_contents($json_url);
$decoded = json_decode($json);
$data = $decoded->{'matches'};
foreach ($data as $value) {
    print_r($value->team1->logo_url);
    echo '<img src="http://dailydota2.com/' . $value->team1->logo_url . '">';
}
```

It returns following output, and I do not get any errors.

```
/images/logos/teams/cdecgaming.png/images/logos/teams/teamempire.png
/images/logos/teams/ehome.png/images/logos/teams/ehome.png
/images/logos/teams/fnatic.png/images/logos/teams/cloud9.png
/images/logos/teams/teamissecret.png/images/logos/teams/teamissecret.png
/images/logos/teams/natusvincere.png/images/logos/teams/fnatic.png
```

Again I really do not know which information you want to get from the API but here you have a base of working code that you can work further with to get the required data from the right KEYs.

Comment: thanks yeah i mean logo_url sorry now can i show my results in html? when i trying to do this `<img src="http://dailydota2.com/<?php echo  $value->team1->logo_url ?>">
<img src="http://dailydota2.com/<?php echo  $value->team1->logo_url ?>">` its just show me last result how i can show all results?

Comment: inside the foreach put this line: `{    echo '<img src="http://dailydota2.com/' . $value->team1->logo_url . '">'; }` it will show all images and you can mark //print_r etc...

Comment: thank you so much for help :) have good day sir and sorry i can't plus your rep because i need 15 rep in my self or somthing like that

Comment: You are welcome if you have been happy for my answer please check it as answer.

Comment: @jackson please check this as answer

Answer (score 1):

1. Ok so the url your are using return ***VALID*** JSON, no need to change any of it!
2. I suggest using arrays, it has always appeared simpler to me
3. Do you want the `logo_url` from `team` or `image_url` from `league`?  I will show both in my implementation.

So here is some corrected code

```
$json_url = "http://dailydota2.com/match-api";
$json = file_get_contents($json_url);
$decoded= json_decode($json,true); // True turns it into an array
$data = $decoded['matches'];
foreach ($data as $value) {
    //I am not sure which one you want!!!
    echo $value['league']['image_url'] . "<br>";
    echo $value['team1']['logo_url'] . "<br>";
    echo $value['team2']['logo_url'] . "<br>";
}
```

***EDIT** To show wanted implementation by questions author...

```
$json_url = "http://dailydota2.com/match-api";
$json = file_get_contents($json_url);
$decoded= json_decode($json,true); // True turns it into an array
$data = $decoded['matches'];
foreach ($data as $value) {
    echo "
        <img src=\"http://dailydota2.com/{$value['team1']['logo_url']}\">
        <img src=\"http://dailydota2.com/{$value['team2']['logo_url']}\">
    ";
}
```

Comment: thanks...works fine now can i show my results in html? when i trying to do this `<img src="http://dailydota2.com/<?php echo  $value['team1']['logo_url'] ?>">
<img src="http://dailydota2.com/<?php echo  $value['team2']['logo_url'] ?>">`its show me just  last result how can i show all results in html?

Comment: @jackson I added the implementation that you need!